# How to target a div<> with a link, using php?

Tags: javascript, ajax, navigation

What's the best way to target a particular `<div>` with a selection from a menu using php?

Specifically, I want to have a link selected from a menu contained in `div id=menu` loaded in `div id=content`.

I can see this has been discussed in here, but I can't seem to find a clear answer. So, my apologies if this is rehashing an old topic, but I gather that I need to use ajax for this, or can it be done with php only? Are there any good examples or tutorials available?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need AJAX and a bit of magic.

HTML

```
<div id="menu"><a href="page.html">Page 1</a> | <a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

JavaScript (with jQuery)

```
$("#menu a").each(function(e){ 
    $(this).bind("click", function(event){ 
        $("#content").load($(event.target).attr("href"));
    });
});
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work. Basically you want to bind to all the links within `#menu` and when one is clucked load the href into `#content` via an AJAX call.